# What Are The Design Patterns Used In PHP (either in function or library or wherever)

Tags: php, codeigniter, design-patterns, php-7

I have seen in java language that most of the libraries are built with design patterns (singleton, facade, factory and so on).

Is there a recommended resource for PHP 7 and codeigniter 3 libraries for design patterns? I would like to better understand the design patterns I should use.

Please exclude singleton as it is used by CI for database object creation.

Comment: Why down vote for this ? Its good to know that design patterns usage in PHP.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html but @NathanKing is right

Comment: I join @nathan-king and indofraiser that this is rather a general programming question. You can also check https://laracasts.com/series/design-patterns-in-php Please also mind that CodeIgniter is less up to date with trends happening in the PHP world in the last 6-7 years, so as far as I see you'll see less design patterns in the CI world compared to eg. Symfony, Laravel, Zend or Phalcon. This is also stated on the welcome page of their docs: "_a framework that does not require you to adhere to restrictive coding rules._"

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a general programming question rather than PHP specific - any OOP design pattern and be applied to any OOP language in some form or another. The most commonly used are Singleton, Factory, Facade and Repository. You can implement any pattern you like, just as you can in other languages such as Java. I'll give you a couple of implementation examples - don't use it as production code, they're simplified examples.

The Factory pattern is useful when you need to resolve classes.

Use case: You have an API that allows an admin to reject or approve a new user creation request - the admin simply passes the API endpoint a string of `'approve'` or `'reject'`. But we never work with strings. Ever. Instead, we want to represent the actions in classes that implement a common `Action` interface. We can implement a Factory to resolve a class from the provided string like so:

```
interface Action
{
    public function getUsername(): string;
}

class Approve implements Action
{
    private $username;

    public function __construct(string $username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
}

class Reject implements Action
{
    private $username;

    public function __construct(string $username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
}

class ActionFactory
{
    public static function create(string $action, string $username): Action
    {
        switch (strtoupper($action)) {
            case 'APPROVE':
                return new Approve($username);
                break;

            case 'REJECT':
                return new Reject($username);
                break;

            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Expected string `APPROVE` or `REJECT` - `$action` provided");
        }
    }
}
```

(Bonus points for noticing that we're implementing two design patterns here: singleton & factory)

---

The facade pattern is also used a lot (Laravel facades are NOT facades, don't confuse them with real facades). The most common use of the facade pattern is to provide a database connection to a repository. Again, there'll be two patterns here: Facade Pattern and Repository Pattern. I'll leave the method bodies out for this, but it should give you an idea of the use. I don't recommend actually using the methods below - it's incredibly over simplified for the purposes of example.

```
class Connection
{
    public function __construct(string $connectionString);

    public function update(string $table, string $query);

    public function insert(string $table, array $data);
}

class UserRepository
{
    public function __construct(Connection $connection);

    public function createUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->connection->insert('users', $user->toArray());
    }
}
```

You could then have as many repositories as you want and they will all take the `Connection` facade as a dependency in their constructor which provides the interaction to the database.